# Missing message or attachment error while sending message in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating Facebook in my app and I could do with ease,but I am facing a problem when I am trying to post a message with hyperlink on the wall, when I am trying to do this I am getting Missing message or attachment OauthException code 100, I was able to post a message without hyperlink. This is the code which I am using for posting on wall:

```
JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

attachment.put("message", "Messages");
attachment.put("name", "click");
attachment.put("href", "http://www.facebook.com");
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("attachment",attachment.toString());
response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");`
```

Can any one tell me where I am going wrong? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "Messages");
parameters.putString("name", "click");
parameters.putString("link", "http://www.facebook.com");
response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Comment: @ Niraj thank you for your suggestion,but I need to display a hyperlink in the message.I think link key will not do this.

Comment: You post a hyperlink using the 'link' object. It will use the OpenGraph tags to render information from the link. Use the API Explorer to test it.